# <h> tag different color in different page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make that a h1 tag as two colors, for example in the "main page" the h1 is red, and in the "secondary page" the h1 is blue.

I'm trying to achieve this without success, I been doing this with a span but I would like to know if there is another way to do this.

this is my code structure

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, li, ul, ol, a, a:hover, button { color: red; }

h1 .h1cor{
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Wordpress typically adds body classes to themes. Check for a unique body tag and select that way. You could do `body.page-id-XXX h1 { // color }`

Comment: @TyBailey soo, in the css of the webpage in question, I put body.page-id-main-page h1 { color="blue" }

Comment: No it wouldn't say `main-page`, it will be an actual numerical ID. Not all themes provide this, but many of them do. Right click > View Source and check for any body classes.

Comment: @TyBailey I cannot seem to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an ID like this:

```css
#secundarypage h1{
color:red;
}

#mainpage h1{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainpage">
  <h1>Heading for mainpage</h1>
</div>

<div id="secundarypage">
  <h1>Heading for secundary page</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: can I have multiple tags in the id, for example #mainpage h1, h2, h3 {color="red";}

Comment: Yes, not a problem at all. You can use it as you would normally do.

Answer (score 2):

every **page** throws a unique **class** or **id** in the page,
take the class or id of the page as your reference to style **h1** tag;
**for example;**

`<body class="page-class">`

```
.page-class h1{
    color:blue;
 }
```

Comment: That's not true that *every* page has a unique class. Some themes don't put the `body_class()` function in. It's poor theme development, but it can't be ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

First get the page name you are currently in by using this

```
var url = window.location.href
 var getLink = url.split("/").pop();
```

Then set the color according to the name of the page

```
if(getLink == 'mainPage'){
  $('h1').css("color","red");
}else if(getLink == 'secondary page'){
  $('h1').css("color","yellow");
}
```